# Can't write duplicate key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, duplicates

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1022: Can't write; duplicate key in table 'dependent'
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `mydb`.`DEPENDENT`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------


 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`DEPENDENT` (
          `Essn` CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
          `Dependent_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `Sex` CHAR NULL,
          `Bdate` DATE NULL,
          `Relationship` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`Dependent_name`, `Essn`),
          CONSTRAINT `Essn`
            FOREIGN KEY (`Essn`)
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`EMPLOYEE` (`Ssn`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB
```

> SQL script execution finished: statements: 10 succeeded, 1 failed
>
> ```
> Fetching back view definitions in final form.
> Nothing to fetch`enter code here`
> ```

Am getting this error. Can some one help me on this. Thanks

Comment: hi you have primary key defined on the  Dependent_name if you try to insert same name 2 times you will get error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi you have primary key defined on the  Dependent_name if you try to insert same name 2 times you will get error  So you have to define other primary key if you expect duplicate name a common approach id to use auto increment column as primary key but you can define composite keys as well for primary key